# Bug with graphene.Mutation?

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

I use graphene-django for have a GrapQL API.
I have created a mutation in my **schema.py**:

```
class UpdateApplication(graphene.Mutation):
    class Input:
        id = graphene.String()
        name = graphene.String()

    application = graphene.Field(ApplicationNode)

    @classmethod
    def mutate(cls, instance, args, info):
        name = args.get('name')
        rid = from_global_id(args.get('id'))[1]
        update_application = Application.objects.filter(id=rid).update(name=name)

        return UpdateApplication(application=update_application)



class Mutation(ObjectType):
    update_application = UpdateApplication.Field()

schema = graphene.Schema(mutation=Mutation)
```

When I run this resquest, I have an error.

```
mutation update {
  updateApplication(id: "QXBwbGljYXRpb25Ob2RlOjE=", name: "foo") {
    application {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

The error:

```
mutate() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)
```

I put 4 arguments in mutate() not 5... Is it a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of graphene 1.0, the context is now passed to mutation and resolve functions by default whereas it required @with_context in previous versions:
https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/master/UPGRADE-v1.0.md

So your mutate functions should look like:

```
def mutate(self, args, context, info):
    name = args.get('name')
    rid = from_global_id(args.get('id'))[1]
    update_application = Application.objects.filter(id=rid).update(name=name)

    return UpdateApplication(application=update_application)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I fixed it but that does not solve my mistake.

Comment: Sorry... I foolishly copied what you had written ... There is no decorator now as the documentation says... Thanks for help.

Comment: @Yacine Filali it must be:  def mutate(cls, instance, args, context, info):